# how to install CDT for eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

i have installed eclipse on ubuntu 10.04,i want to run C and C++ program, what is the commant to install CDT for it, i have installed eclipse Galileo, i tried help -> install new softwares and added  this link http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo but it shows no repository , please help...

Answer (score 5):

1. don't use the eclipse from ubuntu -- it is out dated
2. download from eclipse.org directly, choose [the cdt](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr1) one

Answer (score 0):

To install Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu just type these command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

Assuming that you have a Ubuntu installed with internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just press Alt+Cnt+T and type sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt this is only when you have already eclipse installed in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories.
2. Go to terminal and type the following command : 
   sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++